# Can "thank you for the laptop" mean the same as "thank you for fixing the laptop"?

Tags: american-english

The title pretty much covers it. The context is Person A has finished fixing the laptop and the Person B expresses gratitude for the job in a casual way. I consulted with ChatGPT, and it said the phrases mean different things. Its answer is below.

> "Thank you for the laptop" expresses gratitude for the gifting or provision of the laptop itself, implying appreciation for the act of giving or providing the laptop to the speaker.
>
> On the other hand, "thank you for fixing the laptop" expresses gratitude for the specific action of repairing or resolving issues with the laptop.

However (!!!) I strongly believe that on more than one occasion I've heard the phrase "Thank you for [the thing]" in a context that would imply "Thank you for [helping out with the thing]." So, I'm puzzled.

Comment: Please do not use Chatgpt for questions like this because it obviously does not work. In linguistics, this would come under Pragmatics.

Comment: Yeah, "*consult with ChatGPT*" is a *contradictio in terminis* :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, the most likely meaning of "Thank you for the laptop" is "Thank you for giving me the laptop". But in a conversation where both people are familiar with the situation, it could be understood as a shorter way of saying "Thank you for (what you did regarding) the laptop".

(Note that ChatGPT merely pieces together text it has seen on the web so that it looks like a plausible answer. The answer may or may not be correct.)

Comment: Thank you A LOT! I felt like ChatGPT was gaslighting me with the answer so I created an account here to check if I truly had been wrong all this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for fixing the laptop. **is very specific.**

That said, if someone does you a favor of any kind with regard to any object (laptop, car, window etc. etc.) or even a person, the context will tell you if just "for the x" works because the interlocutors will know that it refers to having it repaired or fixed or even, for example, giving someone a ride somewhere. So, the answer to the question is: yes. You don't have to specify it further in these cases.

Comment: THANK YOU! As for the ride case ("thanks for the ride"), at first I considered it, too, but then I recognized that this would imply someone giving someone a ride (i.e. providing it), which is not the case that I was wondering about.

Comment: @notanativespeakerbuttryin It does not matter what it's for if the people talking to each other know what is being referred to. This would be the same in ANY language. How many ways can I say this? It applies to anything.